Any way to include "npm install react-scripts --save" in a React app github repository? Or is it always needed to install after installing the repo?
Any way to include "npm install react-scripts --save" in a React app github repository? Or is it always needed to install after installing the repo?
I am curious if its normal for someone to clone my github repo and then need to "npm install react-scripts --save" in order to launch my react app. Or is there a way to include it in my original repo so when cloning you dont have to type "npm install react-scripts --save" into the console in VScode.
Thank you,
Wes
I tried cloning my github repo, which mostly worked fine aside from needed to type "npm install react-scripts --save" into the console to have "npm start" work and launch the app in the web browser locally.
